# Validation API show correct logs in APEX but saving record that is not validated

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, api

I have an API like this:

`https://app.test.com/test.php?umcn=UMCN`

Now those are examples when I hit that API with a number at the end:

`https://app.test.com/test.php?umcn=1234` > `{"success":false,"message":"UMCN is invalid. UMCN must be 13 numbers long."}` >> `Not enough numbers`

`https://app.test.com/test.php?umcn=1234123412344` > `{"success":false,"message":"UMCN is is invalid. Verification code is not correct."}` >> `13 numbers but wrong validation`

`https://app.test.com/test.php?umcn=s` > `{"success":false,"message":"UMCN is invalid. UMCN must be numeric."}` >> `Because I insert 'S'`

So that is when I do it manually.

So I'm creating a form in salesforce to save a Student, I have a field for this UMCN number, and I created an APEX class to fetch API.

`APEX:`

```
  public class ValidationService {
  @AuraEnabled public static Map<String, Object> validateUmcn(long umcn) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://app.test.com/test.php?umcn='+umcn);
      req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    if(res.getStatusCode() == 400) {
      return new Map<String, Object> {
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Empty or is not a number'
      };
    }
         if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
      return new Map<String, Object> {
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Empty or is not a number'
      };
          }
    return (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
  }
}
```

And in my LWC component, I have this inside my JS to check the form and save it:

```
    saveForm() {
    console.log('student for save => ', JSON.stringify(this.studentRecord));
    createRecord({ apiName: STUDENT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields: this.studentRecord })
        .then(student => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'student created from saveForm => ' + student.id,
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
}
async handleFormSubmit(event) {
    // Prevent saving here
    console.log("em ehere")
    event.preventDefault();
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    const validationResult = await validateUmcn({ umcn: fields.UMCN__c});
    if(validationResult.success) {
        console.log("validation is  sucess")
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    } else {
        console.log("validation is not sucess")
        this.showInfoToast;
            }
  }
```

What is the problem?
When I populate fields and for field UMCN that has validation through API that I provide above, for example I insert for UMCN:

Form > Field UMCN > I insert 1 >
Logs in APEX show appropriate response code and correct message `{"success":false,"message":"UMCN is invalid. UMCN must be 13 digit long."}` >> `Not enough numbers` and record is not saved.

Now whenever I insert for field UMCN inside form number that is 13 digit long for example:

Form > Field UMCN > I insert 1234567890123 that record is saved, even I get correct Error in APEX logs `{"success":false,"message":"UMCN is is invalid. Verification code is not correct."}` >> `13 digits but wrong validation`

And that is for every number that is 13 digit long, every number that have 13 digits is saved as record even in Apex logs I get a good response code and message that it shouldn't be saved.

What can be problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
  return new Map<String, Object> {
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'Empty or is not a number'
  }
};
```

Here, you're ignoring whatever error message was returned, if any, and stating `success` is `true`. The server is returning 200, but returning an JSON that has a `success` flag of `false`.

All you should be doing here is returning the value you received:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://app.test.com/test.php?umcn='+umcn);
req.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
return (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
```

The client can read the success/error for itself, assuming that the service you are calling is always supposed to return a JSON value.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Great, thank you so much for helping me during this stuff, I learned a lot. Thank you again.